# How to get header when error http in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, http-headers

I want to get header http when i have an error in my call of api

```js
this.http.get('/monapi',{responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' })
.subscribe( (res) => 
{ 
    // I have http-header here in object res debugger; 
    console.log(res); 
}, 
(error) => { 
    // But here, i have no http header :(
    debugger; 
    console.log(error); 
} );
```

I do not see how to do it :(

Thanks for your help

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need http-header in error?

Comment: Because, the api send message in header when a error occured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it that way **error.headers**,  [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) have headers property:

```
(error: HttpErrorResponse) => { 
  debugger; 
  console.log(error.headers); 
}
```

Comment: I've already try this solution, but i found the problem. I have an interceptor that delete the header.  Now it's work. Thanks a lot